# How to add in title a date but with other color, like in iMDb titles?

Tags: posts

Is there a way to add in title a date but with another color, like in iMDb titles?

Like in this title (click on it): http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606378/

**To be more clear,** [see this picture](http://postimage.org/image/75pgjx62x/)

**The result is this:**[see this picture](http://postimage.org/image/5v9b99v6p/)

Thanks!

Comment: *It works perfect*. ***Thanks!*** There are several problems.
This function changes all data on my website, it add the date time everywhere.
I would like to add the date only in title.
Is there a way to add/or edit data ***(2012)*** manually? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

add this code in functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ta_modified_post_title');
function ta_modified_post_title ($title) {
    global $post;   
    $mynewdate = strtotime($post->post_date); 
    $title = $title.'<span class="modified">'.date('Y',$mynewdate).'</span>'.'-<span class="modified">'.date('d',$mynewdate).'</span>-'.'<span class="modified">'.date('m',$mynewdate).'</span>';
  return $title;
}
```

modify date by your own way.